# C++ Selection Sort (vectors)

Tags: c++, sorting

```
int temp;
for (int j = 0; j < vecsize - 1; ++j) {

    int min = sort.at(j);
    for (int i = j+1; i < vecsize; ++i) {
        if (min > sort.at(i)) {
            min = sort.at(i);  
            temp = i;
        }

    }  
swap(sort.at(j), sort.at(temp));
}
```

I am trying to sort (in ascending order) the vector of:             23 42 4 16 8 15

However, my attempt at using selection sort outputs: 4 8 15 23 16 42

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend using `operator[]` instead of `at`, as the latter does bounds checks. If you know to be within bounds that check is wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : [corrected-code](http://ideone.com/mwcDC9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print (vector<int> & vec) {
    for (int i =0 ; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
int temp;
vector<int> sort;

sort.push_back(23);
sort.push_back(42);
sort.push_back( 4);
sort.push_back( 16);
sort.push_back( 8);
sort.push_back(15);
print(sort);

int vecsize = sort.size();
for (int j = 0; j < vecsize - 1; ++j) {

    int min = j;
    for (int i = j+1; i < vecsize; ++i) {
        if (sort.at(min) > sort.at(i)) {
            min = i;
        }

    }  
    if (min != j)
        swap(sort.at(j), sort.at(min));
}

print(sort);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you define min, you seem to be assigning it the value of the array sort at jth index. Yet, you are using an extra variable tmp to swap the elements, and you seem to fail to initialize it before the inner for loop, similar to how you initialize min. And if all the other elements in the array are smaller than the element at sort[j], tmp will be uninitialized for that iteration of the outer loop, possibly causing it to have an incorrect value in it.

```
int temp;
for (int j = 0; j < vecsize - 1; ++j) {
    int min = sort.at(j);
    temp = j;                                     # HERE'S WHAT'S NEW
    for (int i = j+1; i < vecsize; ++i) {
        if (min > sort.at(i)) {
            min = sort.at(i);  
            temp = i;
        }
    }  
    swap(sort.at(j), sort.at(temp));
}
```

You may see this code at work [here](http://ideone.com/lTFdyR). It seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: Is my code, more or less, the proper way to implement selection sort? (after using your fix)

Comment: Since you did not provide the entire function, one could not possibly comment on how good the code is. After all, we don't even know the type of the variable *sort*. So, without knowing much about the code inhibits our ability to analyze the time and space complexity of your code. That being said, your implementation looks fairly similar to a generic selection sort pseudocode, and it can be considered as a typical implementation, I guess.

Answer (score -3):

If you can use C++11, you can also solve sorting (as in your example) with lambdas. It's a more powerful and optimized way. You should try it maybe in the future.

[EDITED]:

A short example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;

    myVector.emplace_back(23);
    myVector.emplace_back(42);
    myVector.emplace_back(4);
    myVector.emplace_back(16);
    myVector.emplace_back(8);
    myVector.emplace_back(15);

    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(),
       [](int a, int b) -> bool
    {
       return a < b;
    });
}
```

Comment: OP wants to implement selection sort. Your example shows how to use the already implemented `::std::sort` (which, btw. you could directly use with `::std::less`). So this should rather be a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This was my first post on Stack overflow. I am new to SO so I can't write comments, because to low reputation and I overlooked the "selection" sort. My mistake. Thank you.